# Simple Moving Average Column-Wise in R

Tags: r, forecasting

So I clean revenue data every quarter and I need to do the two quarter moving average to predict the next five year quarterly revenue for each individual product (I know this will just end up being the same average for now). Attached here is the data frame: [Revenue Df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Nqz.png)

Right now I have the data in wide format, and you'll see I created the empty forecasting columns by have the user enter a start and end date for the forecast, then it creates the columns for every quarter between. How can I fill these forecast using a moving average? I also converted it to long, and still could not figure out how to fill the forecast. Also I know the 9-30-2020 shows in the forecast, we want to replace that with the actuals even if the user inputs that date for the forecast.

```
for(i in ncol(Revenue_df)){
  
  if(i<3)
  {Revenue_df[,i]<- Revenue_df[,i]}
  else{
  Revenue_df[,i]<-(Revenue_df[,i-1]+Revenue_df[,i-2])/2
  }
  
}
```

```
Product<- c("a","b","c","d","e")
Revenue.3_30_2020<- c(50,40,30,20,10)
Revenue.6_30_2020<- c(50,45,28,19,17)
Revenue.9_30_2020<- c(25,20,22,17,24)


revenue<- data.frame(Product,Revenue.3_30_2020,Revenue.6_30_2020,Revenue.9_30_2020)

forecast.sequence<- c("2020-09-30","2020-12-31","2021-03-31","2021-06-30","2021-09-30","2021-12-31","2022-03-31"
 "2022-06-30","2022-09-30","2022-12-31","2023-03-31","2023-06-30","2023-09-30","2023-12-31","2024-03-31"
"2024-06-30","2024-09-30","2024-12-31")


forecast.sequence.amount<- paste("FC.Amount.",forecast.sequence)
revenue[,forecast.sequence.amount]<-NA
```

I tried this code and it did not work, any suggestions? Also attached is the code for the sample data frame shown in the picture, sorry for the bad format this is my second time asking a question on here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bit simple for a product forecast.  You might want to look at the `forecast` and `fable` packages for forecast functions that can account for trends and seasonality in forecasts.  These would, however, require for than two data points of data.  Anyway, taking your problem as given, the following code seems to do what you describe.

#### EDIT

I've made the forecast calculation a function to make it more straightforward to use.

```
library(tidyverse)

product<- c("a","b","c","d","e")
Revenue.3_30_2020<- c(50,40,30,20,10)
Revenue.6_30_2020<- c(50,45,28,19,17)
Revenue.9_30_2020<- c(25,20,22,17,24)
revenue<- data.frame( Product = product, Revenue.3_30_2020,Revenue.6_30_2020,Revenue.9_30_2020)

rev_frcst <- function(revenue, frcst_end, frcst_prefix) {
#      
#  Arguments:
#     revenue = data frame with 
#               Product containing product name
#               columns with the format "prefix.m_day_year" containing product quantities for past quarters
#     frcst_end = end date for quarterly forecast
#     frcst_prefix = string containing prefix for forecast
#     
#  convert revenue to long format
#     
 rev_long <-  revenue %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Product, names_to = "Quarter", values_to = "Revenue") %>%
            mutate(quarter_end = as.Date(str_remove(Quarter,"Revenue."), "%m_%d_%Y")) 
 num_revenue <- nrow(rev_long)/length(product)      
#
#  generate forecast dates
#
 forecast.sequence <- seq( max(rev_long$quarter_end), 
                         as.Date(frcst_end),
                         by = "quarter")[-1] 
#
#  Add forecast rows to data
#
  rev_long <- rev_long %>% 
              bind_rows(expand_grid(Product=unique(revenue$Product), quarter_end = forecast.sequence) %>%
                        mutate(Quarter = paste(frcst_prefix, quarter_end)) ) )
#
#  Define moving average function
#
 mov_avg <- function(num_frcst, x) {
   y <- c(x, numeric(num_frcst))
   for(i in 1:num_frcst + 2) { 
      y[i] <- .5*(y[i-1] + y[i-2]) }
  y[1:num_frcst + 2]
 }
#
# Calculate forecast
# 
  rev_long_2 <-  rev_long %>% group_by(Product) %>% 
                 mutate(forecast = c(Revenue[1:num_revenue],
                                 mov_avg(num_frcst =length(forecast.sequence),
                                         x = Revenue[1:2 + num_revenue - 2]))) %>%
             arrange(Product, quarter_end)
}
#
#  call rev_frcst to calcuate forecast
#
  rev_forecast <- rev_frcst(revenue=revenue,
                        frcst_end = "2024-12-31",
                        frcst_prefix = "FC.Amount.")
```

which gives

```
   Product   Quarter               Revenue quarter_end forecast
   <chr>     <chr>                   <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
   1 a       Revenue.3_30_2020          50 2020-03-30      50  
   2 a       Revenue.6_30_2020          50 2020-06-30      50  
   3 a       Revenue.9_30_2020          25 2020-09-30      25  
   4 a       FC.Amount. 2020-12-30      NA 2020-12-30      37.5
   5 a       FC.Amount. 2021-03-30      NA 2021-03-30      31.2
   6 a       FC.Amount. 2021-06-30      NA 2021-06-30      34.4
   7 a       FC.Amount. 2021-09-30      NA 2021-09-30      32.8
   8 a       FC.Amount. 2021-12-30      NA 2021-12-30      33.6
   9 a       FC.Amount. 2022-03-30      NA 2022-03-30      33.2
  10 a       FC.Amount. 2022-06-30      NA 2022-06-30      33.4
```

Comment: Hey WaltS, when I try forecasting it gives me this error: Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 100 rows.
x Assigned data has 20 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.    It seems that it is not accounting for the group by and only calculates the first 20 observations for the forecast so it will not fill the data frame. Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: I've made the change described above.  Let me know if this has a problem.

Comment: I figured out it was my issue because I did not specify dplyr for mutate (apparently there is another package with a mutate function that I have). So sorry about taking up your time WaltS, thank you again so much for your help!